# How to disable -webkit-app-region: drag;?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-app

I have a [chrome-app](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/about_apps) and I made the entire window draggable by adding `-webkit-app-region: drag;` to a `div` via a css class:

example:

```
<style>
    draggable {
        -webkit-app-region: drag;
    }
</style>

<div class='draggable'>
    hello world
</div>
```

The **problem** is that I **cannot disable the dragging** by removing the `draggable` class from the `div`(for example via jQuery or chrome-debugger). Besides this being a potential bug, are there any workarounds to stop the `div` from making the app window draggable?

FYI: I have checked this on Chrome(34.0.187.116), Chrome Beta(35.0.1916.69), Chrome Canary(36.0.1964.2) and all have the same behavior. OS: MacOS X 10.9.2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a workaround. By hiding the `div` via `display: none` the draggable can be disabled.

Comment: I know how to file a chromium bug, but where can I file a chrome bug? - just saw it. will do.

Comment: filed a [bug](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=368352&thanks=368352&ts=1398797585)

Answer (score 6):

I'm currently building an application in electron (formerly atom-shell). Around the time of arriving to your question, I found a way to solve this and just like anything else, the answer is really simple.

Take this example as my instance and solution:

1) Your problem is that anything in the div block (including the div) will be draggable, and you lose some functionality (e.g. clicking though to links contained within), right?

```
<div style='-webkit-app-region:drag'>...</div>
```

If you want to have your anchors within that drag region:

```
<div style='-webkit-app-region:drag'>
<a href='index.html'>...</a>
<a href='about.html'>...</a>
</div>
```

Become clickable, all you need is do is exactly as you said:

> I cannot disable the dragging

Disable the Dragging... And here's the code to prove it.

```
<a style="-webkit-app-region: no-drag;" href="index.html">...</a>
```

Not only does that stop drag capability on that element, it will also allow you to click through to events being prevented by webkit.

Answer (score 3):

just use on those particular elements the rule `-webkit-app-region:no-drag` its all

Comment: perfect, does the job

Answer (score -1):

`-webkit-app-region:no-drag` dont works so i just created a another div **`.drag-overlay-div{position:absolute; z-index:1000; -webkit-app-region:no-drag}`** now activating/deactivating this .drag-overlay-div using `display:none/display:block`